# parsing c commands: char*, char** confused

Tags: c, parsing, string-parsing

I read in c commands saved in `char*` (so basically a "string" of commands) byte by byte.

For example, `"echo a; echo b"`.

Suppose I have `char *wd = (char *)malloc(20);`, and as I read a byte, store in `wd[i]`.

If i see `'e'`, `wd[0]='e'`, `wd[1]='c'`, `wd[2]='h'`, `wd[3]='o'`, `wd[4]='\0'`.

And I set set `word[0]=wd;`.

Then, repeat the loop which allocate space for wd again.
Set wd[0]='a', wd[1]='\0', and word[1]=wd;

My code looks like this:

```
for(i=0; i<strlen(input);i++)
{
    if(validChar(input[i]))
    {
        printf("valid char:%c\n", input[i])   
        wd[k]=input[i];
        k++;
        cIndex++; 
    }

    else if(input[i]==' ')
    {
        wd[cIndex]='\0';
        printf("wd: %s\n",wd);
        word[wIndex]=wd;
        printf("word %d: %s\n", wIndex, word[wIndex]);
        wIndex++;

       ....
    }
}
```

Here's the problem:
when I print, word0=a and word1=a as well.

I'm confused because c doesn't have string and I have to use char*. 
So when I "copy" the string, it's not copying the content, but the pointer so it's value changes.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you can include a "String" library: #include <string.h>

Comment: also, in order to copy you can use: strcpy(destination, source);

Comment: Never do this `for(i=0; i<strlen(input);i++)`, `strlen()` computes the lenght of the string, it's not stored anywhere, so that could get very very expensive, do it like `for (i = 0 ; input[i] != '\0' ; ++i)` since if `strlen()` returns the correct length of the string it's almost surely because the string is correctly `nul` terminated, hence you can use the same condition that `strlen()` uses to determine the end of the string. And beware that `char *` is a pointer, not a string, a string is built up by the pointed to content.

Comment: @vivoconunxino word is array of pointer. what should I change it to so that it won't print the current value of wd?

Comment: @iharob thanks for pointing out strlen()! changed to input[i]!='\0'.

Comment: @user3121023 can you explain a little bit more about strdup? I'm new to C and I'm having really hard time how to implement this.
not sure if im doing right but in this case, should i do "char* strdup (wd);" and how should I save this to word?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate new memory for each word. You say that you do this, but there is no code for it in your example.

```
char *wd;
for(i=0; i<strlen(input);i++)
{
  wd = malloc(20);  // Added line. Allocate a chunk of memory for the next word
  if(validChar(input[i]))
  {
    printf("valid char:%c\n", input[i])   
    wd[k]=input[i];
    ...
```

Note that this code will suffer a buffer overrun if the input contains words longer than 19 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

sample separate to word by `strtok_r` and copy word by `strdup`
(note : both non-standard function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    char input[256] = "echo a; echo b";

    int word_max = 256;
    char **word = malloc(word_max * sizeof(*word));
    char *command_p, *com_sp;
    int wIndex = 0;

    command_p = strtok_r(input, ";\n", &com_sp);//separate by ";"
    while(command_p){
        char *wd, *wd_sp;
        wd = strtok_r(command_p, " ", &wd_sp);
        while(wd){
            word[wIndex++] = strdup(wd);//make copy
            if(wIndex == word_max){
                word = realloc(word, (word_max += 8)*sizeof(*word));//check omitted
            }
            wd = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &wd_sp);
        }
        command_p = strtok_r(NULL, ";\n", &com_sp);
    }
    //print & relese
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < wIndex; ++i){
        printf("word %d: %s\n", i, word[i]);
        free(word[i]);
    }
    free(word);
    return 0;
}
```